# How to know if you are sending correctly a JSON message in java

Tags: java, json, nginx

I want to know how can you know if you are sending correctly a Json message by reading the response.

I'm actually receiving this message:

```
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.0 201 Created [Server: nginx, Date: Thu, 11
Sep 2014 21:01:52 GMT, Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8,
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block,
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, Location:
http://newduoc.efizity.com/api/telemetry_consumptions/16, ETag:
"cf80e1320a6e11352acb0a9dc17d9f75", Cache-Control: max-age=0, private,
must-revalidate, X-Request-Id: 341e5904-bb0b-4451-b0fb-f45690c0a43c,
X-Runtime: 0.010819, X-Cache: MISS from router.dhemax.cl,
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from router.dhemax.cl:3128, Via: 1.0
router.dhemax.cl (squid/3.1.10), Connection: close]}
```

The method that I'm using to send the post json message is this one:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(Config.urlJSON);
StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());
request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.setEntity(params);

Log.debug(httpClient.execute(request).toString());

httpClient.close();
```

Basically I'm just doing a .toString() to the CloseableHttpResponse object returned by the CloseableHttpClient object.

I'm using java-json to send the Json message and it looks like the server is ngix.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found the way of getting the server response and understand it.

I don't know if this is a standard but when you use the method getStatusCode you get the code:

```
httpClient.execute(request).getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

At least in this case the server send this codes. I repeat, I'm not sure if this is for all the servers but at least this one goes for me I think it is a nginx server:

- 422: Incorrect data.
- 400: Json structure invalid.
- 401: Access not allowed.
- 201: Correct.

So basically the code goes like this:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(Config.urlJSON);
StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());
request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.setEntity(params);
int statusCode = httpClient.execute(request).getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
Log.debug("[STATUS:[" + String.valueOf(statusCode) + "]");
```

All the magic goes by the `CloseableHttpClient obj.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();`